# Laravel validation 'exist' not working in master-slave DB configuration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, validation, master-slave

I am moving the project to Master-Slave configuration and got a problem, that validation related to DB stopped working for me. Any ideas what I'm missing?

so here is validation part:

```
$request->validate([
  'property_id' => 'required|exists:mysql.property,p_id',
  ... other validations not related to DB ...
], $error_messages);
```

file config\database.php :

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',

    'write' => [
        'host' => '196.168.56.211',
    ],
    'read' => [
        'host' => '192.168.56.222',
    ],
    'port' => '3306',
    'database' => 'project_db',
    'username' => 'db_user',
    'password' => 'pass123',
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET'),

    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
],
```

this is what i'm reciving:

in file \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php [663]:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new QueryException(
        $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    );
}
```

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] An attempt to establish a connection was
>   unsuccessful, because The required response was not received from the
>   other computer within the required time, or the already established
>   connection was terminated due to the incorrect response of the already
>   connected computer.  (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from
>   `property` where `p_id` = 2444)
>
> and this is happens when laravel try to connect to 'write' database.
>   But from MySQL workbench - connecting & editing records fine.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

change your config to

```
 'mysql' => [
    'write' => [
        'host' => '196.168.56.211'
    ],
    'read' => [
        'host' => '192.168.56.222',
    ],
    'sticky'    => true,
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'project_db',
    'username'  => 'db_user',
    'password'  => 'pass123',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
],
```

This ensures that any data written during the request cycle can be immediately read back from the database during that same request

[official document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#configuration) read for more info

Comment: can you try removing 'strict' => false and check ? also run php artisan config:clear b